# dynamically add images to view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a carousel in my Xamarin application. Here I need to add navigation "dots" below my carousel, in order to intuitively show the user which slide is shown in the carousel.

The Carousel is initialized from a List of objects, which may vary in size, which naturally means that I have to place a corresponding amount of dots at runtime.

Currently, I have bounded a ViewModel to my View, which updates the content of the carousel through a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. 
The updates are currently controlled with a timer.

To summarize, I want to know, how I can add `<Image>` elements via code-behind in a .xaml file. 
Furthermore, I want to understand how I can identify them uniquely so that I can access them and change the image, based on which page is shown in the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add an `Image` (or any element) to a View at runtime

```
// XAML
<StackLayout x:Name="stack">
  ...
</StackLayout>

// in code behind
stack.Children.Add(new Image() { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you Jason! I thought about this, but is it a proper way to do it, if I want to uniquely identify them?

Comment: you can use the AutomationID or ClassID to assign an identifier to them, or otherwise maintain your own data structure to track references